# Firefox extension + TCP : "navigator is not defined"

Tags: javascript, firefox, tcp, firefox-addon, mozilla

I'm trying to build an extension for firefox inspired by http://mike.kaply.com/2011/01/18/writing-a-firefox-protocol-handler/

> Firefox add-ons can add new schemes or protocols to the browser. This
>   post will show you how to do that.

The deployement of this 'basic' extension is OK.

Now, I'd like  to create a TCP connection as described in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TCP_Socket_API

to get a **mozTCPSocket** (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator.mozTCPSocket) ,  an object **navigator** ( https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator ) is needed.

But my extension says that **navigator is undefined.**

As far as I understand, I first need to find the **window** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.navigator

how can I get this **window.navigator.mozTCPSocket** ? I'm looking for a solution that doesn't use the sdk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need access to the `navigator` object, and even in that case you would discover that currently `mozTCPSocket` is not enabled by default. Also notice that the TCP Socket API is marked as Firefox OS only.

The good news is you can create one directly.

```js
var socket = Cc["@mozilla.org/tcp-socket;1"].createInstance(Ci.nsIDOMTCPSocket);
```

Comment: What's `Cc` in this Context?

Comment: @alsed42 `Components.classes`